# Lambda expression as function parameter

Tags: c#

I have the following code

```
List<int> GetIndices<T>(List<T> list, ?????? condition
{
    var result =
            list
                .Select((p, index) => index)
                .Where(condition);

    return result.ToList();
}
```

And I would like to call it like `GetIndices(someList, (p, index) => (someList[index].Height < someList[index - 1].Height))`

What is the correct type of `condition`?

Answer (score 4):

There's an error in your code: `Where` expects a delegate that returns a `bool` value and has the list element type as input.

```
var result = list
   .Select((p, index) => index) // projects the element to it's index (of type int)
   .Where(condition);           // => expects Func<int, bool>
```

So you would need `Func<int,bool>`

However, from your spec I think you want `Func<T,int,bool>`, which means you have to rewrite your implementation of `GetIndices` as

```
var result = list
   .Select((p, index) => new {p, index}) 
   .Where(x => condition(x.p, x.index))
   .Select(x => x.index);
```

Comment: The `Enumerable.Where` method also has an overload accepting a Func<T, int, bool>.

Comment: @Tesserex: but then you loose the original index, I think

Answer (score 1):

```
Func<T, bool>
```

Should do the trick but you're going to have to modify your lambda a bit because you can't pass the index (if you want to use condition in the `Where` clause). You could easily change your lambda to:

```
p => someList[someList.IndexOf(p).Height < someList[someList.IndexOf(p)-1].Height
```

For future reference, the MSDN documentation for the extension methods is great once you learn how to read it (that part takes a bit):

[MSDN - Enumerable.Where Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.where.aspx)

Since this is an extension method, the first parameter (`IEnumerable<TSource>`) is the collection you're calling the method on (`List<T>` in your case).

The second parameter is what you need to match. Since the documentation calls for `Func<TSource, bool>` and `TSource` is `T` in your case...you get `Func<T, bool>`

Comment: this should work, with the small caveat that if `someList` is large you might have introduced a performance problem here (`IndexOf` is an O(N) operation)

Answer (score 1):

Like jeroenh realized, you need to capture the original index. The `Funct<T,int,bool>` condition you pass only needs to be aware of the item and its index, not the anonymous type created in the query, so the condition passed changes a bit. It also should handle the situation where the index == 0 and therefore there are no preceding items (index - 1).

```
class Program {
    static void Main( string[] args ) {
        var items = Item.GetItems();
        // mind the case where index == 0 so you don't grab an item out of bounds
        var ind = GetIndices( items,
            ( p, index ) => ( h.index == 0 ) ? false : p.Height < items[ index - 1 ].Height );
    }

    static List<int> GetIndices<T>( List<T> list, Func<T, int, bool> condition ) {
        var res = list
            .Select( ( item, index ) => new { item, index } ) // capture original index
            .Where( h => condition( h.item, h.index ) )
            .Select( h => h.index ); // reduce to the index again
        return res.ToList();
    }
}

class Item {
    public int Height {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public Item( int h ) {
        Height = h;
    }
    static public List<Item> GetItems() {
        return new List<Item>( new[]{
                     new Item(1),
                     new Item(4),
                     new Item(2),
                     new Item(5)
        } );
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks overly complicated. I might be better off not using linq?

Comment: Yes, it could be done simpler, maybe even with LINQ. If you use `Where()` first, it will accept a `Func<T,int,bool>` and pass the index. Nothing wrong with a `for` loop, either, and the `Func<>` condition can still be passed and used.

Answer (score 0):

Try [`Func<bool>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534960.aspx).

Or rather [a variant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534647.aspx) with the correct amount of input parameters.